Reference request for studying arithmetic soundness of ZFC
For context, I recently read the answer by Nik Weaver here. I am intrigued and want to learn more about the topic of arithmetic soundness in the context of ZFC. I've had enough of sitting and trying to read stuff on the internet. I actually want to read a comprehensive book and not be an armchair mathematician. I want to get all the detail I actually need to understand the meaning of this statement.

Other than a vast amount of stuff I've read on the internet, I have read through the chapters of Elements of Set Theory by Enderton. I suppose there'd be multiple books, then, to bridge the gap required to go from set theory to meta-mathematics and the statement I'm interested in in particular, but what would they be?

This is my first time asking a reference-request question, so feel free to point out what I can do better!
